# jquery and an if statement

Tags: javascript

Drupal 7. I have a radio button set. When one of the items is selected I would like it to set the node add title to some string. This is as far as I got, but I get the error: "TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a function (evaluating '$("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink")')"

```
(function ($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.cgps_helpdesk_misc = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
          $("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").change(function ($) {
              if ($("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").attr("checked")) {
                alert('Handler for .change() called.');
                $('#edit-title').val($('#edit-title').val() + 'bla bla bla');
              }
          });
        }
      };
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Remove the $ from the chane handler parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

What MPD is saying is change this line:

```
$("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").change(function ($) {
```

to this:

```
$("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").change(function () {
```

You have declared two functions as $ and that may be killing the script.

Comment: I did try that and it still threw an error

Comment: What is the error? Because the answer above is correct. If anything it should be .change(function(event){}) because an event object is passed to that function, That is why $ no longer works in the function and you have to use jQuery instead, the $ variable is now a an event object, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Actually, I'll just post the whole code that should work as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cgps_helpdesk_misc = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").change(function (eventObject) {
          if ($("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").attr("checked")) {
            alert('Handler for .change() called.');
            $('#edit-title').val($('#edit-title').val() + 'bla bla bla');
          }
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

The only part that was wrong in the original is `.change(function ($)`
This part is overriding the $ variable which is a jQuery object and setting it to an event object. The change event send an event object to the listener functions.

The question is already answered, but I thought it would be good to try to explain what is actually going on to give the op a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I have a feeling the jQuery substitution of the $ is not the "Drupal 7 way", and I would be curious to know what that way is, but this works:

```
(function ($) {
      Drupal.behaviors.cgps_helpdesk_misc = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
          $("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").change(function ($) {
              if (jQuery("#edit-field-i-need-help-with-und-printer-ink").attr("checked")) {
                alert('Handler for .change() called.');
                jQuery('#edit-title').val(jQuery('#edit-title').val() + 'bla bla bla');
              }
          });
        }
      };
    }(jQuery));
```

Full solution at http://agerson.net/setting-title-field-based-radio-button-node-add-form-drupal-7-jquery